# Bash terminal not wrapping text correctly

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am using the `gnome-terminal` with bash, and when I have a command that should go over the line, it just stays on the same line. So instead of:

```
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I would get

```
opqrstuvwxyz""abcdefghijklmn
```

Or something similar to that. However, if I press enter the command will still work. I believe it has something to do with my PS1 variable, but I don't know what is wrong with it. Here it is:

```
export PS1='\e[1;35m[\u:\w]\$\e[0;35m '
```

Comment: Confirmed. This PS1 causes the issue also in `konsole` (KDE).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems somewhat related:

> Wrapping the `tput` output in `\[ \]` is recommended by the Bash man page. This helps Bash ignore non-printable characters so that it correctly calculates the size of the prompt.

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Bash_escape_sequences).

"The `tput` output" in your case looks like this: `\e[1;35m`, `\e[0;35m` (there are two separate fragments to wrap). They could be written as `\033[1;35m` and `\033[0;35m` as well. In general you need to wrap any non-printable sequence.

I modified your `PS1`:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;35m\][\u:\w]\$\[\e[0;35m\] '
```

and it seems to work for me without the issue.