# Sometimes ctrl+a doesn't go to the start of line

Tags: bash

I found that in bash, sometimes when I press ctrl+a the cursor doesn't jump to the start of line, or well, it does, but on the screen it seems like it jumps to the middle of the line.

I'm on osx, I use iTerm and terminal and get the same behaviour. [Here's an example](https://v.usetapes.com/uKgc47ktA1) When the line gets longer, ctrl+a (or in my case, cmd+a) gets out of sync with the terminal input

Comment: Please provide some more information about your OS, the terminal used, ideally a screenshot that shows the issue, and indicate what you've tried to solve the issue. Does the problem occur in a different terminal emulator? In a different shell? Do you have any special shell configuration?

Comment: Your prompt uses color. Check your `PS1`. [This link](https://superuser.com/q/1221588/432690) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kamil I was able to solve the mystery, it was the PS1 (prompt).
I changed the value

```
\e[0;32m[\u@\h \w]$ \e[m
```

to

```
\[\e[0;32m\][\u@\h \w]$ \[\e[m\]
```

and now it works!