# bash prompt messed up on arrow up

Tags: command-line, bash

I have made some modification to my prompt with use of colors via tput.

It looks like now when I try to do an `arrow up` lookup after few moves up, the prompt is being cut into half, what I mean by this is:

From this:

```
PROD mysuer@server1.domain.com:~$ vim .bashrc
```

To this:

```
PROD mysuer@servegit rebase origin/add_pool
```

`ctrl + c` brings everything back to normal.

I have found some posts indicating that this may be due to the issue with missing escapes for `[` however I don't see an issue here:

My code:

```
#red for prod, green for lab

COLOUR_RESET=$(tput sgr0)
COLOUR_GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
COLOUR_BLUE=$(tput setaf 6)
COLOUR_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
COLOUR_RED=$(tput setaf 1)
BOLD=$(tput bold)

if [[ $HOSTNAME =~ .*\.domain.com$ ]]; then
  COLOUR=$COLOUR_RED
  PROMPT_TEXT="PROD"
fi

if [[ $HOSTNAME =~ .*\.lab$ ]]; then
  COLOUR=$COLOUR_BLUE
  PROMPT_TEXT="LAB"
fi


MYPROMPT="$COLOUR$BOLD$PROMPT_TEXT$COLOUR_RESET \[\u@$COLOUR$BOLD$(hostname -f)$COLOUR_RESET:\w\]\$ "

PS1=$MYPROMPT
```

UPDATE:
@KamilMaciorowski has pointed out a similar question although it was not relating to a tput colors.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it's a little bit different, although thanks to you other post I was able to narrow it down to the fact that the issue with with injecting variables particularly `PROMPT_TEXT=` although I had to change the `$MYPROMPT='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m$($PROMPT_TEXT)\]\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

Answer (score 2):

My answer [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/a/1221598/432690) is almost sufficient, you should wrap the output of `tput` in `\[ \]`.

Almost sufficient, because you already have `\[ \]` in *wrong* places; you should get rid of them. [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says:

> `\[`
>   begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
>
> `\]`
>   end a sequence of non-printing characters

This means that e.g. `$(hostname -f)` should be outside any `\[ \]`. So either

- remove `\[` and `\]` from the explicit `MYPROMPT` definition and replace every `=$(tput …)` with `='\['"$(tput …)"'\]'`;

or

- change only the `MYPROMPT` definition. I adjusted your original one:

  ```
  MYPROMPT="\[$COLOUR$BOLD\]$PROMPT_TEXT\[$COLOUR_RESET\] \u@\[$COLOUR$BOLD\]$(hostname -f)\[$COLOUR_RESET\]:\w\$ "
  # printing                ^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^
  # non-pr.   ^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

Answer (score -1):

At the end I had to drop the tput colors.

My final prompt:

```
if [[ $HOSTNAME =~ .*\.domain.com$ ]]; then
  PROMPT_TEXT="PROD"
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]$PROMPT_TEXT\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\H\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
fi

if [[ $HOSTNAME =~ .*\.lab$ ]]; then
  PROMPT_TEXT="LAB"
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;34m\]$PROMPT_TEXT\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\H\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
fi
```