# Bash Output-Prompt

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, prompt, stdout

So i'm customizing my PS1-Bash-Prompt at the moment and found the iPython way of displaying in- and output pretty neat.

[image: Terminal Screenshot of Prompt and iPython]

As you can see, i have my PS1-Prompt configured to look (almost) like the iPython-Input Prompt.

```
PS1="\n[\t] \e[1m\e[38;5;196m\u@\H\e[0m in \e[1m\e[38;5;196m\w\e[0m\n\e[92mIn [\e[1m\#\e[0m] \$ "
```

However i can't figure out how to display an Output-Prompt in Bash!

What i'm actually looking for is a way to display a message and increment a counter, whenever a command returns an output to stdout (being able to customize stderr-output would also be nice).

Can someone tell me if and how this can be achieved? Is there a good argument against my idea?

Comment: Forget it. The key difference is: when python prints something, python knows what it's printing. When you execute a command from bash, it's not bash producing the output, it's that external command producing it, and bash has no idea what that command prints. For this to work, you'd need to send the output through some filter, but only for apps that simply produce output, not for text editors and such.

Comment: On an unrelated note: You need to enclose PS1's escape sequences within `\[` `\]` pairs, otherwise line editing falls apart badly.

Comment: Ok thank you! That's quite helpful. Are the user- / host- / time-specification also considered as escape-sequences? I must confess that i had some line-issues since i changed the prompt.

Comment: No, what you should enclose between those characters are where bash thinks that the cursor will advance, but it actually won't. Silly bash doesn't recognize `\e[...m` as a sequence that doesn't move the cursor. `\u` and friends are unrelated to this and should not be enclosed.

Comment: You could have the last process's return code in $PS1...

Comment: @TimHilt You may find [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1368273/432690) useful when it comes to what to enclose in `\[` `\]`.