# What's wrong with this PS1-Prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt, escape-characters

I was styling my PS1-Prompt to resemble the iPython-Prompt as:

```
PS1FIRSTLINE="\[\n\][\t] \[\e[1m\e[38;5;196m\]\u@\H\[\e[0m\] in \[\e[1m\e[38;5;196m\]\w\[\e[0m"
PS1SECONDLINE="\n\e[92m\]In [\[\e[1m\]\#\[\e[0m\]] \$ "
PS1="$PS1FIRSTLINE$PS1SECONDLINE"
```

[image]

However, sometimes i get weird issues like, that the beginning of the last executed command is still there after the prompt and can't be deleted.

I think that it's an issue with my way of escaping the colors with `\e[ ... ]` and not something with bash or the suckless-terminal, that i'm using.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1368273/432690) of mine.

It's not immediately clear whether `\n` should be considered printing or non-printing, or if the division is the same as printable vs. non-printable (like in the context of [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)).

When it comes to `PS1`, however, I would say `\n` should be called "printing" because it affects the size of the prompt and this is what matters here. You should put both occurrences of `\n` outside of `\[ \]`.

The first `\n` is explicitly inside `\[ \]`. The second one (at the beginning of `PS1SECONDLINE`) looks like it's not at the first glance, but it is as well. There is an unmatched `\[` in `PS1FIRSTLINE` and when the whole `PS1` is created the matching `\]` comes from `PS1SECONDLINE`.

These are your variables with proper modifications that put `\n` outside of `\[ \]`:

```
PS1FIRSTLINE="\n[\t] \[\e[1m\e[38;5;196m\]\u@\H\[\e[0m\] in \[\e[1m\e[38;5;196m\]\w\[\e[0m\]"
#             ^^ deleted embracing \[ \]                                    added closing ^^
PS1SECONDLINE="\n\[\e[92m\]In [\[\e[1m\]\#\[\e[0m\]] \$ "
#                ^^ added opening
PS1="$PS1FIRSTLINE$PS1SECONDLINE"
```