# xshell - how to display the command line and the result line in different colors?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

Could anyone give me some instructions on how to display the command line and the result in different colors.

Currently, they have the same color so it is difficult to read.
I am using XShell 5.

[image]

Comment: Isn't XShell a terminal emulator? It could distinguish the command from the result if you used local echo. Usually you don't want local echo (nor local line editing) while ssh-ing to Linux. So do you use local echo? If not, it's the shell what prints the command, it could distinguish it from the result. What shell are we talking about? Please [edit] the question and add these details. It's more common to apply colors to the command prompt.

Comment: I have no idea what shell you are asking. All I know is I am using xshell5. You can refer to the snapshot i just added. The command (in yellow box) and the result are all white, so It is difficult for me to see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what XShell5 is, but on my Centos servers, I add this line to .bashrc

```
export PS1='[\[\033[32m\]\u@\h\[\033[36m\] \W\[\033[00m\]]\$ '
```

Once you have saved the file, type:

```
. .bashrc
```

You should have a green command prompt.  Your command won't be a different colour, but it makes it easy to distinguish between the line you typed your command on and the output of that command.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Bash:

```
export PS1='\[\e[31m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[32m\]'
#           ^^^^^^^^^^                        this part is responsible for red prompt
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ this part is responsible for green command echo
preexec_invoke_exec() { printf '\e[0m'; }
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        this resets
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

The trick is `PS1` finally sets text color to green, so any command you type will be green. After you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> but before the command is run, the trap is activated. It resets text, you should get normal white output.

Notes:

- You can learn more color codes [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124407/108618).
- `\033` and `\e` in various examples on the Internet are the same thing.
- While building your `PS1` remember you need `\[` and `\]` to indicate non-printable characters, otherwise [weird](https://superuser.com/q/1376666/432690) [things](https://superuser.com/q/1221588/432690) will happen.
- Commands can still print in color (e.g. `ls --color=always`).
- You don't have to create `PS1` anew. This line will modify your *current* `PS1` so the command is green:

  ```
  PS1="$PS1"'\[\e[32m\]'
  ```
- You should always (re)set text properties at the beginning of `PS1` as if the trap never happened, because it may not happen (e.g. after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> the prompt is redrawn without triggering the trap).
- If some (background) process writes to your terminal while the shell awaits your command as normal, its output will be colored as command.