# How to get the length of a prompt?

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

Is there a way that I can determine the length of a prompt? Is there a way that I can look at the `PS1` variable and get the length from it and repeat characters for the same length?

I am trying to create a new terminal prompt for the bash command.

Comment: The length of a prompt is going to be dynamic, depending on the variables you're using, such as user, directory, host and so on. Please give some specific example. What's your prompt, and what's your expectation. You can check by `echo $PS1`. Also, what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: So is there a way that I can look at the PS1 var and get the Length from it and repeat chars for the same length?

Comment: What's your goal? What do you want your prompt to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `PS1` is well written then it encloses non-printing fragments in `\[ \]`. You need to get rid of these fragments first. Normally I would use `sed` but I don't think one can easily do non-greedy matching with `sed`, hence `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's|\\\[.*?\\\]||g' <<<"$PS1"
```

A newline inside `\[ \]` would make `perl` not remove the fragment. This [shouldn't happen](https://superuser.com/a/1377581/432690) with well written `PS1`, so it's not a problem.

You need the result in a helper variable:

```
ps="$(perl -pe 's|\\\[.*?\\\]||g' <<<"$PS1")"
```

A separate variable is needed because the next step is to ask Bash to evaluate the string as if it was a prompt; this is easy with a variable.

One thing though: here string (`<<<`) ads a trailing newline, then command substitution (`$( )`) removes *all* trailing newlines. If originally there are no newlines then both phenomena will cancel each other. If there are trailing newlines then you will lose them all and the final result will be off by an unknown number. In a general case we can deal with this by appending a suffix (here `X`):

```
ps="$(perl -pe 's|\\\[.*?\\\]||g' <<<"${PS1}X")"
```

This way both mechanisms cancel each other for sure. Then you can evaluate as if it was a prompt, like this:

```
printf '%s' "${ps@P}"
```

You need the length anyway, so `printf` is not exactly necessary:

```
wc -m <<<"${ps@P}"
```

I think `wc -m` is better than `wc -c` in this context. The result is inflated because of our suffix (of length 1) and yet another additional newline (from `<<<`). Therefore you need to subtract 2.

---

The whole procedure as a function:

```
plen () {
   local ps len
   ps="$(perl -pe 's|\\\[.*?\\\]||g' <<<"${PS1}X")"
   len="$(wc -m <<<"${ps@P}")"
   printf '%s\n' "$((len-2))"
}
```

---

You said you want to

> repeat chars for the same length

Maybe you don't need length for this.

```
pblock () {
   local ps
   ps="$(perl -pe 's|\\\[.*?\\\]||g' <<<"${PS1}X")"
   ps="${ps@P}"
   printf '%s' "${ps::-1}" | tr -c '\n\r' 'M'
}
```

This function will replicate the shape of the prompt even if it's multi-line, although characters like tab are troublesome. Depending on your `tr` multi-byte characters (e.g. `ś`) may also make the function not work as expected.

You may or may not prefer `printf '%s\n' …`.