# zsh prompt messed up on arrow up

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, zsh

I think i had got an error like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1368166/bash-prompt-messed-up-on-arrow-up).
My prompt is

```
PROMPT=$'\n%F{cyan}================================%f\n[%*] [%F{yellow}%?%f]\n[%F{cyan}%n@%m%f]\n[%F{green}%~%f]'
```

For example, i ran:

```
================================
[2022-08-23 14:02:43] [0]
[jyxjjj@DESMG-MacBookPro]
[~]$ php media app:build
```

When i press arrow up keyboard, then press arrow down
it will show:

```
================================
[2022-08-23 14:02:43] [0]
[jyxjjj@DESMG-MacBookPro]
[~]$ php media app:buphp media app:build
```

I am sure that i didn't give a fault sample.
It just show as

```
php media app:buphp media app:build
```

and runs correctly as:

```
php media app:build
```

too.

That means whatever i saw, it runs correct command.

So it just a display error.

Then i tested all ways, only remove PS1/PROMPT export will fix this error.

So i think my PS1 caused this error.

How to fix it?

I didn't understand the answer from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1368166/bash-prompt-messed-up-on-arrow-up).

So i want ask again.

I am very sorry.

Addtional:

some part of my zshrc:

```
autoload -U colors && colors

setopt histignoredups
setopt histignorealldups
setopt appendhistory
setopt sharehistory
setopt promptsubst
```

Then:

```
$ echo $PS1

%F{cyan}================================%f
[%*] [%F{yellow}%?%f]
[%F{cyan}%n@%m%f]
[%F{green}%~%f]$(__git_ps1)$ 

$ echo $PROMPT

%F{cyan}================================%f
[%*] [%F{yellow}%?%f]
[%F{cyan}%n@%m%f]
[%F{green}%~%f]$(__git_ps1)$ 

$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
(nothing)

$ which PROMPT_COMMAND
PROMPT_COMMAND not found

$ which prompt_command
prompt_command not found
```

I tested

```
PROMPT=$'\[\n\]\[%F{cyan}\]================================\[%f\n\][\[%*\]] [\[%F{yellow}\]%?\[%f\]]\n[\[%F{cyan}\]%n@%m\[%f\]]\n[\[%F{green}\]%~\[%f\]]'
```

and it printed the `[` and `]`

I tested

```
PS1='\n\[\e[36m\]================================\[\e[0m\]\n[\t] [\[\e[36m\]\u@\h\[\e[0m\]]\n[\[\e[32m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]'
```

in bash and it works.

Comment: A workaround : You can add a newline at the end, so that the PROMPT lets you type commands on a new line & "arrow up-down" will not have Issues.

Comment: Look for codes to put into you prompt that says "non-printable character(s) follows". Make e.g. {green} be marked as such a "character".

Comment: I'm the author of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1368273/432690) under the question you linked to. That question and my answer is about Bash. I don't know Zsh very well, still I really doubt my answer applies to Zsh. If you wish, I can help you understand my answer, but I think this won't help you in Zsh anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had found the answer by myself:

From zsh manual, Prompt Expansion, Simple Prompt Escapes, [section 13.2.5 - Visual effects](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects).

> `%{...%}`
> Include a string as a literal escape sequence. The string within the braces should not change the cursor position. […]

My code was missing these `%{` and `%}`. They seem to be zsh's counterparts of [`\[` and `\]` in bash](https://superuser.com/a/1368273).