# Command line only in one line

Tags: linux, command-line

I am on Centos 7 and i just created a new VM.

My problem is if I have long command (e.g. iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 172.28.59.0/24 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8090 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.253:80), it only prints on one line (means that it does not go the next line so that the command would be readable)

[This is what happens when the command is long.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj3ww.png)

[This is my expected result when the command is long.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcYqP.png)

Can you please help me?

Comment: Maybe an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly. Perhaps bash thinks the terminal windows is larger than it is?

Comment: The answers from the link did not help me. Wrapping still occurs

Comment: There are a few other post about this issue -> https://superuser.com/questions/1221588/bash-terminal-not-wrapping-text-correctly && https://serverfault.com/questions/303745/server-bash-line-wrapping-over-text-in-wrong-place check those out. They seem to point to bash prompt not knowing its place.

Comment: Are you doing this over SSH, or over "physical" VM console, or over serial console (ttyS0)?

Comment: When I created this VM, one of the settings is [console=ttyS0]. so I guess ttyS0